# SQL Performance: Using OR is slower than IN when using order by

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-performance

I am using MariaDB 10.0.21 and running a query similar to the following query against 12 Million Rows:

```
SELECT 
    `primary_key` 
FROM 
    `texas_parcels` 
WHERE 
    `zip_code`
         IN ('28461', '48227', '60411', '65802', '75215', '75440', '75773', '75783', '76501', '76502', '76504', '76511', '76513', '76518', '76519', '76520', '76522', '76525', '76527', '76528', '76530', '76537', '76539', '76541', '76542', '76543', '76548', '76549', '76550', '76556', '76567', '76571', '76574', '76577', '76578', '76642', '76704', '76853', '77418', '77434', '77474', '77833', '77835', '77836', '77845', '77853', '77879', '77964', '77975', '78002', '78003', '78006', '78013', '78028', '78056', '78064', '78070', '78114', '78123', '78130', '78132', '78133', '78154', '78155', '78359', '78382', '78602', '78605', '78606', '78607', '78608', '78609', '78610', '78611', '78612', '78613', '78614', '78615', '78616', '78617', '78619', '78620', '78621', '78623', '78624', '78626', '78628', '78629', '78632', '78633', '78634', '78636', '78638', '78639', '78640', '78641', '78642', '78643', '78644', '78645', '78648', '78650', '78652', '78653', '78654', '78655', '78656', '78657', '78659', '78660', '78662', '78663', '78664', '78665', '78666', '78669', '78672', '78676', '78681', '78699', '78701', '78702', '78703', '78704', '78705', '78717', '78719', '78721', '78722', '78723', '78724', '78725', '78726', '78727', '78728', '78729', '78730', '78731', '78732', '78733', '78734', '78735', '78736', '78737', '78738', '78739', '78741', '78744', '78745', '78746', '78747', '78748', '78749', '78750', '78751', '78752', '78753', '78754', '78756', '78757', '78758', '78759', '78828', '78934', '78940', '78941', '78942', '78945', '78946', '78947', '78948', '78953', '78954', '78956', '78957', '78963', '92536') 
ORDER BY 
    `timestamp_updated` ASC
LIMIT 1000;
```

I have a compound index on `(zip_code,timestamp_updated)`, I obtain results in **~1.6 Seconds**. In the next query I am still seraching the same zipcodes but I am using **OR** instead of **IN()**.

```
SELECT 
    `primary_key`
FROM 
    `texas_parcels` 
WHERE
(`zip_code` = '28461' OR `zip_code` = '48227' OR `zip_code` = '60411' OR `zip_code` = '65802' OR `zip_code` = '75215' OR `zip_code` = '75440' OR `zip_code` = '75773' OR `zip_code` = '75783' OR `zip_code` = '76501' OR `zip_code` = '76502' OR `zip_code` = '76504' OR `zip_code` = '76511' OR `zip_code` = '78957' OR `zip_code` = '78963' OR `zip_code` = '92536' OR `zip_code` = '76513' OR `zip_code` = '76518' OR `zip_code` = '76519' OR `zip_code` = '76520' OR `zip_code` = '76522' OR `zip_code` = '76525' OR `zip_code` = '76527' OR `zip_code` = '76528' OR `zip_code` = '76530' OR `zip_code` = '76537' OR `zip_code` = '76539' OR `zip_code` = '76541' OR `zip_code` = '76542' OR `zip_code` = '76543' OR `zip_code` = '76548' OR `zip_code` = '76549' OR `zip_code` = '76550' OR `zip_code` = '76556' OR `zip_code` = '76567' OR `zip_code` = '76571' OR `zip_code` = '76574' OR `zip_code` = '76577' OR `zip_code` = '76578' OR `zip_code` = '76642' OR `zip_code` = '76704' OR `zip_code` = '76853' OR `zip_code` = '77418' OR `zip_code` = '77434' OR `zip_code` = '77474' OR `zip_code` = '77833' OR `zip_code` = '77835' OR `zip_code` = '77836' OR `zip_code` = '77845' OR `zip_code` = '77853' OR `zip_code` = '77879' OR `zip_code` = '77964' OR `zip_code` = '77975' OR `zip_code` = '78002' OR `zip_code` = '78003' OR `zip_code` = '78006' OR `zip_code` = '78013' OR `zip_code` = '78028' OR `zip_code` = '78056' OR `zip_code` = '78064' OR `zip_code` = '78070' OR `zip_code` = '78114' OR `zip_code` = '78123' OR `zip_code` = '78130' OR `zip_code` = '78132' OR `zip_code` = '78133' OR `zip_code` = '78154' OR `zip_code` = '78155' OR `zip_code` = '78359' OR `zip_code` = '78382' OR `zip_code` = '78602' OR `zip_code` = '78605' OR `zip_code` = '78606' OR `zip_code` = '78607' OR `zip_code` = '78608' OR `zip_code` = '78609' OR `zip_code` = '78610' OR `zip_code` = '78611' OR `zip_code` = '78612' OR `zip_code` = '78613' OR `zip_code` = '78614' OR `zip_code` = '78615' OR `zip_code` = '78616' OR `zip_code` = '78617' OR `zip_code` = '78619' OR `zip_code` = '78620' OR `zip_code` = '78621' OR `zip_code` = '78623' OR `zip_code` = '78624' OR `zip_code` = '78626' OR `zip_code` = '78628' OR `zip_code` = '78629' OR `zip_code` = '78632' OR `zip_code` = '78633' OR `zip_code` = '78634' OR `zip_code` = '78636' OR `zip_code` = '78638' OR `zip_code` = '78639' OR `zip_code` = '78640' OR `zip_code` = '78641' OR `zip_code` = '78642' OR `zip_code` = '78643' OR `zip_code` = '78644' OR `zip_code` = '78645' OR `zip_code` = '78648' OR `zip_code` = '78650' OR `zip_code` = '78652' OR `zip_code` = '78653' OR `zip_code` = '78654' OR `zip_code` = '78655' OR `zip_code` = '78656' OR `zip_code` = '78657' OR `zip_code` = '78659' OR `zip_code` = '78660' OR `zip_code` = '78662' OR `zip_code` = '78663' OR `zip_code` = '78664' OR `zip_code` = '78665' OR `zip_code` = '78666' OR `zip_code` = '78669' OR `zip_code` = '78672' OR `zip_code` = '78676' OR `zip_code` = '78681' OR `zip_code` = '78699' OR `zip_code` = '78701' OR `zip_code` = '78702' OR `zip_code` = '78703' OR `zip_code` = '78704' OR `zip_code` = '78705' OR `zip_code` = '78717' OR `zip_code` = '78719' OR `zip_code` = '78721' OR `zip_code` = '78722' OR `zip_code` = '78723' OR `zip_code` = '78724' OR `zip_code` = '78725' OR `zip_code` = '78726' OR `zip_code` = '78727' OR `zip_code` = '78728' OR `zip_code` = '78729' OR `zip_code` = '78730' OR `zip_code` = '78731' OR `zip_code` = '78732' OR `zip_code` = '78733' OR `zip_code` = '78734' OR `zip_code` = '78735' OR `zip_code` = '78736' OR `zip_code` = '78737' OR `zip_code` = '78738' OR `zip_code` = '78739' OR `zip_code` = '78741' OR `zip_code` = '78744' OR `zip_code` = '78745' OR `zip_code` = '78746' OR `zip_code` = '78747' OR `zip_code` = '78748' OR `zip_code` = '78757' OR `zip_code` = '78758' OR `zip_code` = '78759' OR `zip_code` = '78828' OR `zip_code` = '78934' OR `zip_code` = '78940' OR `zip_code` = '78941' OR `zip_code` = '78942' OR `zip_code` = '78945' OR `zip_code` = '78946' OR `zip_code` = '78947' OR `zip_code` = '78948' OR `zip_code` = '78953' OR `zip_code` = '78954' OR `zip_code` = '78956')
ORDER BY 
    `timestamp_updated` ASC
LIMIT 1000;
```

This second query obtains the same results in the same order in **~7.8 Seconds**. When running each query through an explain, they are nearly the same, they give me a slightly different `rows` amount.

```
id  select_type     table        type      possible_keys          key            key_len    ref        rows       filtered              Extra
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     SIMPLE     TX_Property   range    Zip Code Search     Zip Code Search       15     (NULL)      2402699     99.88      Using where; Using index; Using filesort  
 2     SIMPLE     TX_Property   range    Zip Code Search     Zip Code Search       15     (NULL)      2321908     99.91      Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

When Profiling the two queries the only major increase in time is the `Sorting Result` time, in the second query it took up to **7.2 Seconds**.

I guess what I don't understand is how the different operator in the where could make such a huge difference when it comes to order, it would make sense if there was a major difference in time for executing? Maybe I am just not exactly sure how profiling works, and it actually is just the time of executing the where portion, but it is just labeled in a convoluted way?

I also wanted to note that when I ran the queries without the `ORDER BY timestamp_updated ASC` the top query took **~0.106 Seconds** and the second query took **~0.157 Seconds**.

Comment: Is column `SitusZip` in the second query the same column as `zip_code` from the first query?

Comment: Yes, they are the same column. Updated the OP to take this into account.

Comment: How long did the `EXPLAIN`, itself, take?  I'm wondering if it takes longer to parse the `OR` variant.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `ORDER BY` runs so much faster because it can stop after only 1000 rows.  How many rows match that OR/IN?

Notice that the `EXPLAINs` say that the query is `Using index`.  That means that you have a "covering" index.  That is all the fields in the `SELECT` are in the one index.

In InnoDB, each secondary key implicitly includes the PK, so `INDEX(zip_code, timestamp_updated)` is effectively `INDEX(zip_code, timestamp_updated, primaryKey)`

The index is not very efficient since you have two non-trivial things going on:  (1) IN or OR, (2) ORDER BY.  Only one or the other can be handled by the index.  Your index lets it use `zip_code`.  It

1. finds the rows *in the index* that match any of those zipcodes,
2. gathers the timestamp and pk, putting the 3 columns in a tmp table
3. sorts
4. delivers the first 1000.

If, instead, you said `INDEX(timestamp_updated, zip_code)` you would still have a 'covering' index, but in this flavor, the index would (I hope) prevent the need for the SORT.  Oh, given that, it might be able to stop after 1000 rows.  Here's how it will work:

1. Scan through the index in timestamp order.
2. Check each row for being one of those zips.  (Here the test *might* be faster in IN format)
3. If match, deliver row; if 1000, stop.

But wait...  Now you are at the mercy of the 12M rows.  *If* 1000 rows with those zips occur early (old timestamps), it can stop fast.  *If* you need to check all the rows to find 1000 (or there aren't even 1000), then it is a full index scan, and this arrangement of the index is 'bad'.

If you give the optimizer both `INDEXes`, it will dutifully make an intelligent choice based on inadequate information (no distribution of the values), and might pick the worse one.

You effectively need a 2-dimensional index.  Such don't exist.  (Well, maybe Spatial could be kludged?)  But...

`PARTITION BY RANGE(timestamp)` together with the `INDEX` *starting* with zip *might* work better.  But I doubt if the optimizer is smart enough to realize that if it found 1000 rows in the first partition it could quit.  And it still fails badly if there aren't 1000 results.

`PARTITION BY RANGE(zip)` together with the `INDEX` *starting* with timestamp *probably* will not help, since that many zips won't do much pruning.

Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...;` for each of your attempts.  There may be some subtle clues there to explain the wide time variations.

Did you run each timing twice?  (Otherwise, caching may have colored the results.)

**Another approach**

I do not know how well this will perform, but here goes:

```
SELECT  primary_key
    FROM  ( 
              ( SELECT  primary_key, timestamp_updated
                    FROM  texas_parcels
                    WHERE  zip_code = '28461'
                    ORDER BY  timestamp_updated
                    LIMIT  1000 
              )
            UNION  ALL (
                SELECT  primary_key, timestamp_updated
                    FROM  texas_parcels
                    WHERE  zip_code = '48227'
                    ORDER BY  timestamp_updated
                    LIMIT  1000 
                       )
            UNION  ALL (
                SELECT  primary_key, timestamp_updated
                    FROM  texas_parcels
                    WHERE  zip_code = '60411'
                    ORDER BY  timestamp_updated
                    LIMIT  1000 ) ... 
          ) x
    ORDER BY  timestamp_updated
    LIMIT  1000
```

It seems like `x` will have only a few hundred thousand rows, not 1.3M.  But `UNION` has some overhead, etc.  Note the `LIMIT` in each subquery and on the outside.  If you need `OFFSET`, too, it gets trickier.

Comment: The above queries match 1.3 Million Rows. I am currently using Mysql 5.5 so I do not have `FORTMAT=JSON`. I checked the query multiple times in each case, so caching was not an issue. With the dataset being as big as it is, the zip codes used actually do limit by quite a lot but the problem is that there are so many rows in that list of zips that it still has a hard time with sorting the data.

Comment: First the code tries to use MEMORY for the tmp table.  If it had succeeded, the sort would be a quick, in-memory, sort.  But with 1.3M rows, it probably spilled to disk (and changed to MyISAM).

Comment: Sorry, I have a lot of performance tricks up my sleeve, but not one for your query.  Well, I'll edit with another approach...

Comment: As you mentioned in _Another Approach_ it would have some issues with Pagination, which is important in my application, but may not be in the the question presented in OP.

I think that the IN that I used in OP is optimized enough for the application that I am using it for, as I have a few tricks to limit further for the search. So I will circle back to the original question. Why is it that using OR over IN is much slower when it gets to the portion of sorting the results down? Is it just mislabeling from the profiler, or is it something quirky happening in the SQL Engine?

Comment: I have not idea why the sort is (or appears to be) slower in one case.  (I was hoping there might be a clue in JSON.)

Comment: @RickJames . . . This is a very informative answer, but I don't see how it answers the question.  The question is about the first two statements, and they both have `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The OP's selects end up sorting 1.3M rows.  My `UNION` has two parts:  The `N` inner selects, thanks to `INDEX(zip, timestamp)` hit 1000 rows without sorting.  The outer select hits `N`*1000 rows from the `UNION`.  So, if there are 100 zip codes, the total will be 0.1 rows to be sorted.  The unknown drawback is the tmp table needed for `UNION` (unless he is running a really new version).

Comment: @RickJames . . . Your query undoubtedly helps the OP.  But the beginning of your answer is about `order by` versus no `order by`.  In the question, both queries have `order by`, it is the `where` clauses that differ.

Comment: @RickJames I Agree with Gordon that the answer doesn't really explain why the difference of time is caused by there where statement. However, After reading through your documents on [indexing cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or) It sounds like **OR**s are converted into **IN**s by the mysql optimizer. Is it possible that the engine is not able to leverage the compound indexes as effectively as when searching by **IN**? I think that this case makes the most sense, especially so if mysql psuedo-converts **OR**s into **IN**s for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pretty long list of zip codes that you are comparing.  MySQL has an optimization that affects why the execution time *without the `order by`* is a bit different. With a list of constants, MySQL sorts the list and does a binary search.  I could see this explaining the last results.

With the `order by`, I am not sure.  The actual execution might be affected by other things running on the server.  Do you know if anything else is running?

Comment: At the time of the queries, this is the only major process that is running, there is nothing using Mysql or anything that is hogging memory or CPU or I/O.

Answer (score -1):

The MYSQL has an optimization , your select when you use OR the number of comparisons increases.

Comment: So it is simply just the number of computations that increase per row that we are querying against, but how does that have to do with the Order by? What you are saying certainly makes sense, but I still have a disconnect from that Increase in computations and the Ordering.

Comment: It would improve this post if some diagnostic were outlined to clearly establish that this reasonable but speculative idea is the cause.  As phrased the Answer is ambiguous and not likely to give the OP an actionable basis for checking similar queries.