# How does Index Scope work in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

In the MySQL manual there is a page on [index hinting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html) that mentions that you can specify the index hinting for specific parts of the query.

> You can specify the scope of an index hint by adding a `FOR` clause to the hint. This provides more fine-grained control over the optimizer's selection of an execution plan for various phases of query processing. To affect only the indexes used when MySQL decides how to find rows in the table and how to process joins, use `FOR JOIN`. To influence index usage for sorting or grouping rows, use `FOR ORDER BY` or `FOR GROUP BY`.

However, there is little to no more information about how this works or what it actually does in the MySQL optimizer. As well in practice it appears to be negligible in actually improving anything.

Here is a test query and what explain says about the query:

```
SELECT 
    `property`.`primary_id` AS `id` 
FROM `California` `property`

USE INDEX FOR JOIN (`Zipcode Bedrooms`)
USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (`Zipcode Bathrooms`)

INNER JOIN `application_zipcodes` `az`
    ON `az`.`application_id` = '18'
    AND `az`.`zipcode` = `property`.`zipcode`

WHERE `property`.`city` = 'San Jose'
AND `property.`zipcode` = '95133'
AND `property`.property_type` = 'Residential'
AND `property`.`style` = 'Condominium'
AND `property`.`bedrooms` = '3'
ORDER BY `property`.`bathrooms` ASC
LIMIT 15
;
```

Explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `property`.`primary_id` AS `id` FROM `California` `property` USE INDEX FOR JOIN (`Zipcode Bedrooms`) USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (`Zipcode Bathrooms`) INNER JOIN `application_zipcodes` `az` ON `az`.`application_id` = '18' AND `az`.`zipcode` = `property`.`zipcode` WHERE `property`.`city` = 'San Jose' AND `property.`zipcode` = '95133' AND `property`.property_type` = 'Residential' AND `property`.`style` = 'Condominium' AND `property`.`bedrooms` = '3' ORDER BY `property`.`bathrooms` ASC LIMIT 15\g
+------+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows | Extra                                              |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | Property | ref    | Zip Bed       | Zip Bed | 17      | const,const                        | 2364 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | az       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 7       | const,Property.zipcode             |    1 | Using where; Using index                           |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So to summarize I am basically wondering how the index scope was meant to be used, as this doesn't seem to do anything when I add or remove the line `USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (Zipcode Bathrooms)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to figure out how multiple hints can be used.  MySQL will almost never use more than one index per `SELECT`.  The only exception I know of is with "index merge", which is not relevant in your example.

The Optimizer usually focuses on finding a good index for the `WHERE` clause.  If it entirely covers the `WHERE`, without any "ranges", then it checks to see if there are `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` fields, in the right order, to use.  If it can handle all of `WHERE, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY`, then it can actually optimize the `LIMIT` (but not `OFFSET`).

If the Optimizer can't consume all the `WHERE`, it may reach into the `ORDER BY` in hopes avoiding the "filesort" that `ORDER BY` otherwise requires.

None of this allows for different indexes for different clauses.  A single hint may encourage the use of one of the above cases (above) in preference to the other; I don't know.

Don't use utf8 for zipcode; it makes things bulkier than necessary (3 bytes per character).  In general, shrinking the size of the table will help performance some.  Or, if you have a huge dataset, it may help perf a lot.  (Avoiding I/O is very important.)

`Bathrooms` is not very selective; there is not much to gain even if it would be possible.

`az.application_id` is the big monkey wrench in the query; what is it?

Comment: Essentially it was a way to make a one to many relationship between a list of zipcodes that I had. [You actually commented on that issue that I was having and this result appears to be the fastest outcome.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256402/sql-performance-using-or-is-slower-than-in-when-using-order-by) This query in the question is actually quite fast if it is using the correct index, however the optimizer tries to pick the wrong one, causing a filesort. As well I cannot remove either index as they are both needed for sorting purposes.

Comment: Wasn't able to edit my last comment again. You said, `Bathrooms is not very selective; there is not much to gain even if it would be possible.` While this is true in a where statement case, it is a lot of rows, so using it as a index for the order by is a lot faster than it would be when using an index on `Bedrooms`. Also wanted to note that I also tried using a giant Union All for the zipcodes, and it was indeed fast, but this needed to be manageable by other developers other than myself so I figured the convoluted abstraction for a minor speed increase compared to current was not worth it.